# WildFly management via reverse proxy fails with XNIO000816: Redirect encountered establishing connection

Tags: wildfly, reverse-proxy, remote-server, traefik

I have Wildfly 10 running on a docker swarm cluster. All HTTP requests go to a Load Balancer (traefik). In traefik (btw. labels in docker stack yml, it works perfectly) `app.wildfly.my.swarm` on port 80 redirects to the Wildfly container's 8080 port and `admin.wildfly.my.swarm` on port 80 redirects to port 9990. In my browser everything is working fine.

But if I try to use the maven wildfly plugin for remote deployment it fails with:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.wildfly.plugins:wildfly-maven-plugin:1.2.1.Final:deploy (default-cli) on project automat: Failed to execute goal deploy. java.net.ConnectException: WFLYPRT0053: Could not connect to remote+http://admin.wildfly.my.swarm:80. The connection failed: XNIO000816: Redirect encountered establishing connection -> [Help 1]

Only if I open the management port directly it works.

Is there anywhere configuration needed to be able to deploy remotely with maven wildfly plugin to wildfly which is behind a proxy?

**EDIT:**

If trying to connect with CLI:

```
./bin/jboss-cli.sh
You are disconnected at the moment. Type 'connect' to connect to the server or 'help' for the list of supported commands.
[disconnected /] connect admin.wildfly.my.swarm
The controller is not available at admin.wildfly.my.swarm:9990: java.net.ConnectException: WFLYPRT0053: Could not connect to http-remoting://admin.wildfly.my.swarm:9990. The connection failed: WFLYPRT0053: Could not connect to http-remoting://admin.wildfly.my.swarm:9990. The connection failed: Connection refused
[disconnected /] connect admin.wildfly.my.swarm:30000
Authenticating against security realm: ManagementRealm
Username: admin
Password: 
Warning! There were errors trying to load extensions. For more details, please, execute 'extension-commands --errors'
[standalone@admin.wildfly.my.swarm:30000 /]
```

Port 30000 is auto-assigned by swarm.

Comment: The `wildfly-maven-plugin` deploys using management operations and therefore requires the management port to be available in order to communicate with the running server.

Comment: But it's still HTTP and the proxy forwards everything to the management port, why should it not work?

Comment: Can you connect with CLI?

Comment: no, CLI can't connect trough the load balancer... I've updated my answer for the console output

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know as much as I should about load balancing so I'm not too sure what the issue could be, but it's got to be on the load balancer/proxy side.

Comment: if I would know what to configure on the LB site, maybe I could solve it. Will try to investigate more later, maybe